# Can't connect to (EWS) Public Calendar Folder Java

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I have created a public calendar folder, but none of the users see it. It should be shared with others.

This is my code:

```
FolderView fv = new FolderView(50);
fv.setTraversal(FolderTraversal.Deep);
FindFoldersResults f = service.findFolders(WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot, fv);
```

The problem is it throws `java.lang.NullPointerException` and

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EWSHttpException: Connection not established
```

When I change it to `WellKnownFolderName.Root` or any other constant like Calendar or Inbox it is working fine. I can review contents with Outlook though.

How can I access public calendar folder with Java if I don't see it and don't know the ID as well?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: There is a working example here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594319/office365-api-admin-accessing-another-users-rooms-calendar-events/39040613#39040613](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594319/office365-api-admin-accessing-another-users-rooms-calendar-events/39040613#39040613)

Comment: Post is quite old but Have you got the solution to this? I am encountering to  same case. Not able to list out folders in public folders.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the email address of the person / resource with the shared folder, then this might work

```
//Create a inclusive view
FolderView fv = new FolderView(100);
fv.setTraversal(FolderTraversal.Deep);

//Find ID of parent calendar
FolderId sharedFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox("email.address@of-thing-sharing-calendar"));

//Find children of that calendar
FindFoldersResults findResults = service.findFolders(sharedFolderId, fv);
```

Comment: it raises an exception microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: It is not valid to specify a mailbox with the public folder root.

Answer (score 0):

There is a working example here: [Can't connect to (EWS) Public Calendar Folder Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918042/cant-connect-to-ews-public-calendar-folder-java#autocomment65433653) It contains a sample java class that should compile and run, using the Java EWS API