# Java program for reading outlook calendar details of user

Tags: java, outlook, calendar, outlook-restapi

I have a requirement to read outlook calendar details of user and display it in table format for given period.

Assume user@abc.com meetings for given period.

I verified the outlook v2.0, didn't get good code samples for connecting outlook server and retrieve user calendar details.

We are using outlook 2013 server.

Update : I found below startup guide to connect outlook from java.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide#get-all-appointments-between-startdate-and-enddate-in-the-specified-folder-including-recurring-meeting-occurrences

Comment: Share your code/workaround so that we can take a look

Comment: I'm looking for examples to start building the logic.

Comment: That isn't how SOF work in most cases. You first show your effort and attempt and then you get help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a working example of getting calendar details here: [Office365 API - Admin accessing another users/room's calendar events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594319/office365-api-admin-accessing-another-users-rooms-calendar-events). It's a working code example. If you follow through in the Javadocs described in the post, you can find the other data items available in the AppointmentSchema and use them, too.