# Get calendar events from Outlook.com using Java API

Tags: java, outlook, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I want to get all calendar events from Outlook.com using Java API. I tested this code to connect:

```
 public void findChildFolders(String username, String password) throws Exception
    {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password);

//        URI jira_url = URI.create("outlook.live.com");
        service.autodiscoverUrl(username, new RedirectionUrlCallback());
        service.setCredentials(credentials);

        FindFoldersResults findResults = service.findFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(Integer.MAX_VALUE));

        for (Folder folder : findResults.getFolders())
        {
            System.out.println("Count======" + folder.getChildFolderCount());
            System.out.println("Name=======" + folder.getDisplayName());
        }
    }

    static class RedirectionUrlCallback implements IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl
    {
        @Override
        public boolean autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback(
            String redirectionUrl)
        {
            return redirectionUrl.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
        }
    }
```

But I get error stack:

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.exception.AutodiscoverLocalException: The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.internalGetLegacyUserSettings(AutodiscoverService.java:742)
```

What is the proper way to implement this code?

Answer (score 0):

A full working example of obtaining a room resource calendar is here: [Office365 API - Admin accessing another users/room's calendar events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594319/office365-api-admin-accessing-another-users-rooms-calendar-events). You can easily adapt the code to obtain the calendar events from the same user that was authenticated, or another user/email/resource if your authenticated user has rights to it.