# Microsoft teams meeting invitation (push notification) in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, push-notification, microsoft-teams, outlook-api

I read this discussion about Outlook emails:
[How to send mail via outlook using spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405168/how-to-send-mail-via-outlook-using-spring-boot)

And I have similar question. In Outlook it is possible to push notification (calendar meetings, **this is not an email**).
I can't find any information about managing such push-notifications in Spring.
Can anybody please help me with it?

UPD: sorry I confused the thing that I need is called "teams meeting invitation", it appears in Outlook on the right side, below calendar

[image]

Comment: uhm maybe you are confusing the service and the mail client

Comment: There may not be (I doubt there is) a bespoke spring project for Outlook calendar meeting push notifications. Seems like you want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38672165/2970947).

Answer (score 0):

Copying answer from comments for better understanding
There may not be (I doubt there is) a bespoke spring project for Outlook calendar meeting push notifications.
Please check this [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38672165/2970947)